# librdkafka - publisher threads per broker

Tags: multithreading, apache-kafka

If I have a single producer instance sending messages to a Kafka Topic, with say 4 partitions, how many threads are necessary?

Say I have 3 servers in the cluster. My understanding is that there would be a leader broker per partition and spread across the machines. Then, the producer would need to talk to each partition leader to send corresponding messages. So I was wondering what should be the theoretical understanding on how many threads are created here? Would it be 1 thread (1 per controller?), 3 threads (1 per server, since 2 partition leaders would live in the same server) or 4 threads (1 per partition?!)

Answer (score 1):

For producers, threads are not associated to partitions or topics.

You can fill a producer buffer as fast as possible, then send to many partitions, of many topics, in one batch request.

So, one thread per CPU core of the client host, would be most efficient. Producers are thread safe, so you should only create one instance, however.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still unsure about what is controlling the number of threads in a producer instance then. Can I assume that it will be one? If messages in the buffer needs to go to multiple partitions, how does that work then? Do all of them go to single node and Kafka handles the mingling? (wouldn't that mean that the leader of a partition is actually not the first to receive a message for a partition?)

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Your code controls thread creation. By default, it'll be one, but you can create more. Records in the buffer have partitions pre-calculated by the partitioner, and the network request will send to every leader partition. Could be multiple nodes, but isn't guaranteed